# How to control view for each user or team?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Let's say I've 10 API's under my account and 10 users. Each user is responsible for their own API.

Is there way to configure in a way that when each user login and go to API gateway they do not see 10 API's and only see the one they're responsible for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by giving resource level permission to each IAM user. As below example, Under the Resource array, you can specify the API ARN for each IAM.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "apigateway:GET"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/a123456789/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please look into the below document for more details.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples.html